# How to get a value of list from for loop in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have list :

```
 l = ['dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/5/free (3) 22.jpg','dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/6/free (3) 24.jpg','dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/7/free (3) 23.jpg']
```

Here I need output as the list consists of 5,6,7 from the list, that is

> [5,6,7]

So for that I tried like below,

```
s= []
for i in l:  
  e = i.split('/')`
  s = e[3]
print(s)
```

when I print s inside the for loop, I am getting the output but if I print outside the loop the output is just 7. Please help me out

Comment: `s.append(e[3])`? you need to add items to the list, not reassign it every iteration.

Comment: `e[3] == 7`, so `s = e[3]` also makes `s == 7`. If you want to keep it a list append not reassign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a list comprehension and get strings…

```
l = ['dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/5/free (3) 22.jpg','dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/6/free (3) 24.jpg','dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/7/free (3) 23.jpg']
out_lst = [fname.split("/")[3] for fname in l]
print(out_lst)

# Output: [‘5’, ‘6’, ‘7’]
```

Or get integers…

```
l = ['dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/5/free (3) 22.jpg','dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/6/free (3) 24.jpg','dataset/Frames_Sentence_Level/are you free today/7/free (3) 23.jpg']
out_lst = [int(fname.split("/")[3]) 
           for fname in l]
print(out_lst)

# Output: [5, 6, 7]
```

I split the list comprehension across lines on the second one because we are doing a lot with the value. Seemed more clear to read.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in just one line using list comprehension:

```
s = [i.split('/')[3] for i in l]
```

the `s` will contains your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are having is because you are **replacing** `s` with the value of `e[3]` within the loop rather than appending `e[3]` to the list `s` - try this:

```py
s= []
for i in l:  
  e = i.split('/')`
  s.append(e[3]) # Note this change!
print(s)
```

While this should work as expected, it's worth noting Mehrdad Pedramfar's use of a comprehension is better for this kind of extraction, although for the uninitiated comprehensions can be difficult to read.